# JAXB generated abstract class not abstract

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I use this schema to generate a java class through JAXB. However, the generated class is not abstract. Also when I include a binding for an implementation class, I am unable to declare that class abstract since Object Factory needs to create an instance. I don't fully understand this. Could anybody help? Thanks !

```
<xs:complexType name="AbstractClass" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="someModel:BaseClass">
            <xs:sequence>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC abstract just says that normaly you won't instantiate this class and it should be used for extension only. So abstract check is up to JAXB and has nothing to do with language-level abstract classes

Answer (score 1):

You should see an abstract class created for abstract complex types (see example below).  Can you provide more details about your XML schema?

**inheritance.xsd**

`contactInfo` is an abstract complex type.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="contactInfo" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="phoneNumber">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="contactInfo">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d out inheritance.xsd
```

**ContactInfo**

The generated `ConactInfo` class is abstract:

```
package generated;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "contactInfo")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    PhoneNumber.class
})
public abstract class ContactInfo {


}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise! But somehow I don't get the same output. I'm using xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6". Is that the problem? Could you please mention what details can be helpful since it's company code :| can't copy paste :(

Comment: @EFreak - I'm curious about how your type hierarchy goes.  Abstract class (abstract) extends someModel:BaseClass (abstract?) extends ? (abstract?).

Comment: Currently it's AbstractClass extends NonAbstractBaseClass1 which again extends another NonAbstractBaseClass2